# Start openvpn client command from a Desktop File?

Tags: gnome, openvpn, 18.10

Trying to create a Desktop File from which I can launch my openvpn connection, but no luck so far.

What I have:

```
david@david-x1:~/Schreibtisch$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.10
Release:    18.10
Codename:   cosmic
```

What I did:

Created a shell script that starts the openvpn connection in /home/david/vpn and it looks like this:

```
    #!/bin/bash
sudo openvpn --config Zurich.ovpn
```

Permission: -rwxrwxr-x  1 david david    46 Feb 10 23:18 vpnswiss.sh

This is working fine. When I execute the script by typing `./vpnswiss.sh` Im asked for the sudo pw and th VPN tunnel will come up.

My Desktop File:

```
 [Desktop Entry]
Name=VPN CH
Exec=bash -c '/home/david/vpn/vpnswiss.sh'
Icon=/home/david/vpn/vpnswiss.png
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Version=1.0
```

I also tried

```
Exec=/home/david/vpn/vpnswiss.sh
```

or

```
Exec=bash -c 'sudo openvpn --config Zurich.ovpn'
```

but it doesnt work. The Desktop File shows up on my desktop just fine, including the correct icon and when I run other applications for test purposes like for example `Exec=firefox` or `Exec=bash -c 'sudo firefox'`, it works instantly. But as soon as Im trying to run openvpn, the terminal window just vanishes after I entered the sudo password. The script is not executed "silently", because when I check ifconfig a few seconds later, theres no VPN connection up.

Any ideas on what I am missing here? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: i am not familiar with desktop shortcuts but two things come to my mind: first - relative vs absolute paths, second - as soon as the terminal windows closes the openvpn connection / tun device will be closed either.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the obvious! It was about the absolute path, of course! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the mistake, thanks to the suggestions in AlexOnLinux comment.

Desktop File was good, but in the Script I needed to use the absolute path:

```
sudo openvpn --config /home/david/vpn/Zurich.ovpn
```

Thanks.