# Running a .sh script from a .desktop file such that script runs on the terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, openvpn

I have so far been able to launch a .sh script using a .desktop file. It so happens that the bash script requires me to enter my sudo password, so in the desktop file I set `terminal=true`. The terminal is displayed, when I click the icon on my desktop (as expected) requesting me to enter my password. However, once I enter my password, terminal closes and my script stops running. The bash script that I'm running is some `sudo openvpn sth.conf` so the script has to be running in the terminal for the VPN to work. How do I prevent my terminal from closing as soon as I enter my password?

Comment: This seems to be a [X-Y](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem. Usually you can import an .opnv file with your networkmanager (using `nmcli`). Care to share why you are using this way?

Comment: @kanehekili I do not possess a .ovpn file, all I have is a .config file which I have to run as ```sudo openvpn something.config```. So what I wanted to do is have a double-clickable icon on my desktop which allows me to connect to the VPN instantly, instead of me navigating to the ```Home``` folder and running a script from there.

Comment: try importing  "something.config" into your Networkmanager. If that doesn't work, we'll look into an alternative

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Start openvpn client command from a Desktop File?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1117474/start-openvpn-client-command-from-a-desktop-file)